# Problem creating a script using Rss for total consumption memory

Tags: scripts, ram

I want to create a script that opens Firefox, loads some urls from a txt file and then records some statistics such as the number of Firefox instances and the total memory consumption (in MB) every 0.5 sec. I want the statistics to be written and saved in file. I know how to find the memory consumption (`grep /proc/"pid"/status VmRSS`) but I don't know how to do it every 0.5 sec and then write it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it using `ps` (see `man ps`) and Gnu `sleep` (see `sleep --help`):

```bsh
# A way to exit the loop - anyone (any other `$USER` process) can rm /tmp/keepgoing
# output in /tmp/logfile
touch /tmp/keepgoing
while [[ -f /tmp/keepgoing ]] ; do
    # $ echo "$(date) $(date '+%N') $(ps -C firefox -o rss= )"
    # Mon Nov 21 19:42:48 EST 2016 185862805 538264
    echo "$(date) $(date '+%N') $(ps -C firefox -o rss= )" >>/tmp/logfile
    /bin/sleep 0.5
done
```

start that going in 1 terminal window, then use `xargs` (see `man xargs`) to feed in your list of URLs in another terminal window:

```
xargs -n 1 /usr/bin/firefox -new-tab </tmp/list-of-URLs.txt
```

Wait until all the firefox tabs have finished loading, then:

```
pkill -9 firefox
rm /tmp/keepgoing
```